# For loop not working with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml

I have a for loop that has `innerHTML` in it and I cannot figure out why it is not working. The code is as below:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function afterload()
{ 
    for(var n=1; n<11; n++)
    {
        document.getElementById("item"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("item"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("prc"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("prc"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("qty"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("qty"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("amt"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("totl"+n).value;
    } 
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="afterload()">
</body>
```

In the body there are table data with the ids above i.e. `item1`, `prc1`, `qty1` and `amt1` and they run up to 10. the parent window also has input fields with the above ids and they also run to 10. The most confusing thing is that if I remove the for loop and write the actual ids of the fields, it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Maybe you don't have all the elements in your HTML?

Comment: Can you provide source data/additional HTML code for reproduce error?

Comment: please provide html too

Comment: try use casting type  "item"+String(n). Have you debugged a code in a browser you will see what is going on.

Comment: Could you provide a (non)working sample we can inspect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function afterload()
{ 
var item = document.getElementById("item");
var itemvalue = document.getElementById("item").value;
var prc = document.getElementById("prc");
var prcvalue = document.getElementById("prc").value;
var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
var qtyvalue = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var amt = document.getElementById("amt");
var amtvalue = document.getElementById("totl").value;
    for(var n=1; n<11; n++)
    {
       item.innerHTML += (itemvalue + "*" + n + "=" + (itemvalue*n) + "<br />");
       prc.innerHTML += (prcvalue + "*" + n + "=" + (prcvalue*n) + "<br />");
       qty.innerHTML += (qtyvalue + "*" + n + "=" + (qtyvalue*n) + "<br />");
       amt.innerHTML += (amtvalue + "*" + n + "=" + (amtvalue*n) + "<br />");
    } 
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="afterload()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function innerHtml(n)
{
        document.getElementById("item"+n).innerHTML =   window.opener.document.getElementById("item"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("prc"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("prc"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("qty"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("qty"+n).value;
        document.getElementById("amt"+n).innerHTML = window.opener.document.getElementById("totl"+n).value;
}

function afterload()
{ 
    for(var n=1; n<11; n++)
    {
       innerHtml(n);
    } 
}
```

Hope its help!